# how can I uniform timestamp format in hive

Tags: regex, apache, hadoop, hive

I have a hive table which has a timestamp column in multiple formats. You can think the following data is a part of it.

```
Steven Li       1994-07-01      Master
Joe Wang        Apr 01, 2001    Phd
James Hou       12-01-99        Master
Al Zhang        10-05-1998      Phd
```

I want to recognize these four formats and uniform them to Unix_timestamp. I use the following code:

```
select name,
    case
        when(regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "yyyy-MM-dd")
        when(regexp_extract(ts, "[a-zA-Z]{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MMM dd, yyyy")
        when(regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MM-dd-yy")
        when(regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MM-dd-yyyy")
    end as ts_ext,
    education
from ts_raw_ext;
```

And the output is:

```
Steven Li       NULL    Master
Joe Wang        986083200       Phd
James Hou       NULL    Master
Al Zhang        NULL    Phd
```

I tested all the regular expressions here on regex101 website, it seems they are all right. But the output is wrong. Who can tell me how can I get my job done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
I made a mistake when I used case statement. I forgot to use the optional expression after case key word. I changed my code to the following and it works:

```
select name,
    case ts
        when regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", 0) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "yyyy-MM-dd")
        when regexp_extract(ts, "[a-zA-Z]{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4}", 0) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MMM dd, yyyy")
        when regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", 0) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MM-dd-yy")
        when regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", 0) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MM-dd-yyyy")
    end as ts_ext,
    education
from ts_raw_ext;
```

And the output of this code is:

```
+------------+------------+------------+--+
|    name    |   ts_ext   | education  |
+------------+------------+------------+--+
| Steven Li  | 773020800  | Master     |
| Joe Wang   | 986112000  | Phd        |
| James Hou  | 944035200  | Master     |
| Al Zhang   | 907570800  | Phd        |
+------------+------------+------------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

The query which you gave is correct. Check in which data type `ts` is in

```
hive> desc ts_raw_ext;
OK
name                    string                                      
ts                      string                                      
education               string                                      
Time taken: 0.477 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive>

hive> select * from ts_raw_ext;
OK
Steven Li   1994-07-01  Master
Time taken: 0.18 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> 
    > select name,
    >     case
    >         when(regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "yyyy-MM-dd")
    >         when(regexp_extract(ts, "[a-zA-Z]{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MMM dd, yyyy")
    >         when(regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MM-dd-yy")
    >         when(regexp_extract(ts, "\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", 0) is not null) then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts, "MM-dd-yyyy")
    >     end as ts_ext,
    >     education
    > from ts_raw_ext;
OK
Steven Li   773020800   Master
Time taken: 0.284 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: Hi Nirmal Ram, thanks for your answer. It doesn't work on my computer. It seems only the first when ---- then pair works.